# Platform.runLater

Tags: java, javafx, observablelist

I have and app that connects to a socket connection and that connections sends me a lot of info.. lets say 300 orders per second (maybe more).. I have a class (it is like a listener, that reacts to some event and that event has the order) that receives that order.. creates an object and then adds it to an ObservableList (which is the source of a tableView).. that way my GUI shows that order. But here comes the problem, if that order already exists on the observableList.. i can't add it ..and i must update it (wich i do).. but some times.. with some orders this condition doesn't work and the order its added again.

Im gonna show you how it's work with some code.

```
 public class ReceivedOrderListener 
 {
     ev = Event; //Supose that this is the event with the order
     if(!Repository.ordersIdMap.containsKey(ev.orderID))
     {    

         Platform.runLater(new Runnable() 
         {
            @Override public void run() 
            {                                                                    
                Repository.ordersCollection.add(ev.orderVo);                        
            }
         } 
      });
      Repository.ordersIdMap.put(ev.orderID, ev.orderVo);
  }
```

Ok now.. this is a resume of my code. The ev is my event with all the info of the order, the orderID is the key that i use to see if the order already exists or not (and yeah is unique). The "Repository" is a singleton class, the "ordersCollection" is a ObservableList, the "ordersIdMap" is a HashMap

Comment: CONT.. in this hashmap i put the "orderID" and the order object, so when a new order arrives i ask if that orderID already exists, if doesnt exist i call to the platform.runLater.. so that way my order is added to the ordersCollection and showed in the tableView, this works fine.. but some times the order already exist and still this code is executed.. I didn't put the else code, but it also updates some orders that already exists (so in some cases.. it works). I think the problem is in the large amount of orders that i receive, cause i seriously recieve like 10000 orders in less than a minute

Comment: Continue.. the GUI doesn't froze but i just have the problem that i mentioned.. maybe the "runLater" can't react that quick and sometimes just cant process the big amount of requests that i do, or maybe im using the wrong method to update the GUI. Anyway i hope someone can understand this and answer (i know my english is very bad, sorry). THANKS!

Comment: how is your listener notified? if it can be called concurrently, then your problem might be caused by they access the same `Repository.ordersIdMap` HashMap concurrently, which is not thread safe. Try to use a [ConcurrentHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html) instead.

Comment: I changed it to ConcurrentHashMap but, it happens the same thing. The listener reads a queue, so imagine i have 1000 orders in a queue.. the listener reads to the first one.. end it and the next one comes in.. thats who it work. I really think that problem is in the Plataform.runLater.. i also put the if condition inside the public void run..and it works better than out side of it.. but still duplicate some orders (much less).

Answer (score 1):

If `ReceivedOrderListener` is executed by multiple threads, then it looks like "check-then-act" race condition.

```
-> ORDER1 comes to the listener
T1 checks ordersIdMap.containsKey(ORDER1) it returs false
T1 proceeds to do Platform.runLater to add the order
-> ORDER1 comes to the listener again
-> T2 checks ordersIdMap.containsKey(ORDER1) it returs false again
now T1 proceeds to do ordersIdMap.put(ORDER1)
-> T2 proceeds to do Platform.runLater to add the order again
```

Comment: I edited my post, cause i was wrong..
The listener reads a queue, so imagine i have 1000 orders in a queue.. the listener reads to the first one.. end it and the next one comes in.. thats who it work, and i still have this problem (so its not multithread). I really think that problem is in the Plataform.runLater.. i also put the if condition inside the public void run..and it works better than out side of it.. but still duplicate some orders (much less).

Comment: Y try it another method..i deleted the "Platform.runLater" and just add the order if it doesn't exist.. AND IT WORKS!!.. BUT!!.. in the output screen JavaFX throws me an error..

"java.lang.NullPointerException at com.sun.javafx.collections.ListListenerHelper$Generic.fireValueChangedEvent(ListListenerHelper.java:291)"

The specific line is Repository.ordersCollection.add(orderVo);
So i think is to quick for the GUI.. 

One method doesnt work at all (Platform.runLater) and the other works but throws me that error..